# How can I send the input value of "radius" to the static method?

Tags: java, static

I'm trying to send the input value of "radius" to a static method in another class called "sphereVolume". However, when I try to send it, it says that I can't make a static reference to the non-static field "radius". And when I try to change "radius" to a static double, it then acts like the method "sphereVolume" doesn't exist. It tries to find it in the "VSAMain" class.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class VSAMain {
    String inputRadius = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter radius:");
    double radius = Double.parseDouble(inputRadius);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sphereVolume(radius);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

`double radius = Double.parseDouble(inputRadius);`

to

`static double radius = Double.parseDouble(inputRadius);`

and to call static method, use

```
sphereVolume.sphereVolume(radius);
```